Apply PCA to multi individual time series dataset
Let's imagine I have time series data for 50 users and 20 features per user: User1_ts(F1, ...F20), User2_ts(F1, ...F20), ...User50_ts(F1, ... F20). F20 is my target variable for estimation, and each time series might be of different length. At the moment, I'm building an AI model to estimate F20. The training dataset is based on the concatenation of 70% of each ts associated to each user. Whereas the train set is built by applying a time windows of 90 days with one day slicing.
My question is related to the approach of applying PCA to reduce the space: when does the PCA should be applied?

Before rolling?
After rolling?
Any other?

I could not find any research paper or other link clarifying such an aspect.
